# Get grayscale Image height without considering white pixels

Tags: c#, image, silverlight, height, bitmapimage

I have grayscale pictures of an `ArrayList<System.Windows.Controls.Image>` laid out horizontally on a `Canvas`. Their `ImageSource` are of type `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage`.

Is there a way to measure in pixels the height of each `Image` *without considering white, non-transparent pixels Outside the colored part* ?

Lets say I have an `Image` of height `10`, in which the whole top half is white and the bottom half is black; I would need to get `5` as it's height. In the same way, if that `Image` had the top third black, middle third white and bottom third black, the height would be `10`.

Here's a drawing that shows the desired heights (in blue) of 3 images:

[image: Example picture]

I am willing to use another type for the images, but it Must be possible to either get from a `byte[]` array to that type, or to convert `Image` to it.

I have read the docs on `Image`, `ImageSource` and `Visual`, but I really have no clue where to start.

Comment: You are going to want to generate a histogram for the rows of the image, then analyze the histogram to find the boundaries of the non-white pixels.

Comment: @Abion47 If I can get a histogram I can probably also simply get and add the RGB on each row to see if it's all white. But how do I even get such data ?

Comment: It depends on what type of object the `Source` for your Image controls is.

Comment: @Abion47 Right, see my edit. The type is `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing pixel data from a BitmapImage is a bit of a hassle, but you can construct a [WriteableBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from the BitmapImage object which is much easier (not to mention more efficient).

```
WriteableBitmap bmp = new WriteableBitmap(img.Source as BitmapImage);
bmp.Lock();

unsafe
{
    int width = bmp.PixelWidth;
    int height = bmp.PixelHeight;
    byte* ptr = (byte*)bmp.BackBuffer;
    int stride = bmp.BackBufferStride;
    int bpp = 4; // Assuming Bgra image format

    int hms;
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        hms = y * stride;
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            int idx = hms + (x * bpp);

            byte b = ptr[idx];
            byte g = ptr[idx + 1];
            byte r = ptr[idx + 2];
            byte a = ptr[idx + 3];

            // Construct your histogram
        }
    }
}

bmp.Unlock();
```

From here, you can construct a histogram from the pixel data, and analyze that histogram to find the boundaries of the non-white pixels in the images.

EDIT: Here's a Silverlight solution:

```
public static int getNonWhiteHeight(this Image img)
{
    WriteableBitmap bmp = new WriteableBitmap(img.Source as BitmapImage);
    int topWhiteRowCount = 0;
    int width = bmp.PixelWidth;
    int height = bmp.PixelHeight;

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            int pixel = bmp.Pixels[y * width + x];
            if (pixel != -1)
            {
                topWhiteRowCount = y - 1;
                goto returnLbl;
            } 
        }
    }

    returnLbl:
    return topWhiteRowCount >= 0 ? height - topWhiteRowCount : height;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, this gives me a few important compiling errors such as:  
`unsafe code may only appear if compiling with /unsafe` and   
`WriteableBitmap does not contain a public definition for 'Lock'` (Same goes for `BackBuffer` and `BackBufferStride`)

Comment: I can activate unsafe compiling, but for the last error I don't know how to fix. Are you sure that's compatible with Silverlight ?

Comment: @Mat I didn't see that you were using Silverlight, my apologies. I don't have a whole lot of experience with Silverlight, but it seems like the recommended approach is to still create the `WriteableBitmap`, but instead reference its [Pixels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.pixels(v=vs.95).aspx) property. (And no, this doesn't require `unsafe` to be used.)

Comment: That definitely seems promising ! If you're willing to write such a solution or just a quick draft of it I'll accept as answer (if of course I get it to work). I'm writing it right now and will try to let you know ASAP, because I can't accept this answer as is.

Comment: @Mat There's your code. The pixel data is in premultiplied ARGB32 format.